# Reading user's PS1 from Swift command-line tool

Tags: swift, bash, ps1

Is it possible to extract the user's PS1 from the environment in a Swift script, so that I can replicate their prompt?

I left a note for myself a few years ago saying that it "disappears from the environment in the context of the script", but I figured it would be useful to ask.

(I'm aware that this question won't necessarily work between shells, but assume that I only care about `bash`. Furthermore, I know I can't necessarily interpret everything in a user's prompt, but I would like to get it).

Comment: PS1 isn't actually in the environment _at all_ in the first place. It's a regular shell variable, not an environment variable, and only environment variables are copied to subprocesses.

Comment: (...like any other shell variable, you can make it into an environment variable with `export PS1`, but that's a bad idea: not all shells specify PS1 in compatible ways, so you don't want a PS1 written for bash to be used by zsh, nor the inverse; also, environment space is a limited resource, stored in the same memory region as command line arguments, so the more you export the shorter your command line length limit is).

Comment: ...also, a lot of `PS1`s aren't really feasible to interpret without a shell. If you have one that invokes `$(someFunction)`, for example, there's no way your swift script will know what that shell function is or how to generate its output. Same thing for a PS1 that relies on shell variables that are set during `PROMPT_COMMAND` execution or such.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: In a system which is set up properly, the inheritance to zsh should not be a real problem, because the user most likely would define PS1 in the .zshrc as well (of course following zsh prompt rules). A  more serious problem seems to me that PS1 can contain embedded code, including code calling a bash function, or expanding other bash variables, and this would be impossible to reproduce inside Swift.

Comment: @Sam: Yous say _Swift **script**_, not _swift **interactive shell**_.  Inside a script - such as bash - the PS1 prompt has no meaning anyway. If Swift allows you to configure the prompt for its REPL-shell, wouldn't it be easier to simply manually set up a prompt according to your likings, instead of converting the prompt from a different language (bash in your case)?

Comment: @user1934428 there are more shells included in MacOS than just zsh and bash -- I just picked an example for familiarity -- and I don't recall there being stock ksh93 dotfiles, f/e.

Comment: The answer from Philippe is about as good as you're going to get without cooperation from the user's shell (of the form of `export PS1` being run before running your script).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I edited my question to clarify that in this case, I only care about supporting `bash`. I'm also aware that I can't necessarily interpret all of the prompt, but I would like to read it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Swift script :

```
bash -i -c 'echo "$PS1"'
```

Comment: That'll tell you what PS1 a _new_ interactive instance of bash would have, not what the _existing_ / parent-process instance was using. If it's changed by activating a virtualenv or such, it won't be reflected.

Comment: Also, needs more quotes. `bash -i -c 'echo "$PS1"'`; otherwise you'll have runs of whitespace collapsed, wildcards expanded, literal tabs and newlines changed to regular spaces, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Corrected, thanks! I know it's PS1 of new instances, but it should cover most of the cases.